# C# Serialize XML to Object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to serializer an XML into an object. I am however, having some trouble. I have gone through maybe postings online regarding an answer, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Please let me explain:

I have the below XML that I want to serialise:

```
<Import_RootObject>
 <Organizations>
  <Import_Organization OrgNr="xxxx">
   <Events>
    <Import_Event StartTime="2012-01-01 09:00:00" EndTime="2012-01-02 12:00:00">
    <Players>
     <Import_Player PersonNummer="1111" />
     <Import_Player PersonNummer="2222" />
     <Import_Player PersonNummer="3333" />
     <Import_Player PersonNummer="4444" />
    </Players>
   </Import_Event>
  </Events>
 </Import_Organization>
</Organizations>
```

Im using four classes to capture this XML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("Import_RootObject")]
public class Import_RootObject
{
    [XmlArray("organizations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("organizations")]
    public List<Import_Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Import_Organization
{
    [XmlAttribute("orgnr")]
    public string OrgNr { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("events")]
    [XmlArrayItem("events")]
    public List<Import_Event> Events { get; set; }

}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Import_Event
{
    [XmlAttribute("starttime")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("endtime")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("players")]
    [XmlArrayItem("players")]
    public List<Import_Player> Players { get; set; }

}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Import_Player
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string PersonNummer { get; set; }

}
```

The code I use to deserialize is:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Import_Organization));
Import_RootObject ei = (Import_RootObject)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(sb.ToString()));
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
<Import_RootObject xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? Hope someone can help out!

Regards,

Bob

Comment: Google Search with key words "There is an error in XML document (1, 2).", you will get a bunch of posts about this

Comment: @David most of which will be completely missing the point for this example...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first obvious error is:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Import_Organization));
```

which should of course be:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Import_RootObject));
```

However, you should also note that xml is case-sensitive:

```
[XmlArray("organizations")]
[XmlArrayItem("organizations")]
```

should be:

```
[XmlArray("Organizations")]
[XmlArrayItem("Import_Organization")]
```

to match the xml; likewise

```
[XmlArray("events")]
[XmlArrayItem("events")]
```

should be:

```
[XmlArray("Events")]
[XmlArrayItem("Import_Event")]
```

and:

```
[XmlArray("players")]
[XmlArrayItem("players")]
```

should be:

```
[XmlArray("Players")]
[XmlArrayItem("Import_Player")]
```

Additionally, note that `<Players>` is **not** a descendant of `Import_Event` - it is part of `Events`. This makes life a little complex.

We then note that your dates are not "starttime" / "endtime", so we can simplify to:

```
[XmlAttribute]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

except... those date/times are not valid xml date/times - they are in the wrong format. So you might have to treat those as `string` data for now.

Finally, your xml is malformed - you have not closed the root element.

Frankly, I'm not surprised the serializer didn't like that :)

Comment: Hi Marc, there are many possible reasons for this "There is an error in XML document (1, 2)." errors, do you agree?

Comment: Hi Marc, you have my undying gratitude! I have implemented your changes and now it works like a charm! Thank for your quick and accurate reply!

Comment: @David sure - check the InnerException to see what the problem actually is