# Populating an object from an XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have an object 'AutoText' which is being populated from an XmlNode (retrieved from a remote source) with the following ctor:

```
public AutoText(XmlNode autoTextNode)
{
    if (null == autoTextNode)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Attempted to create AutoText with null autoTextNode");
    }

    foreach (XmlNode childNode in autoTextNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        string childNodeName = childNode.Name;
        if (childNodeName == "Id")
        {
            this.AutoTextId = childNode.InnerText;
        }
        ... snip ...
        else if (childNodeName == "Autotext")
        {
            this.AutoTextContent = childNode.InnerText;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I know I could do something like:

```
this.AutoTextId = autoTextNode["Id"].InnerText;
```

but presumably this would throw an null ref exception if 'Id' didn't exist, so you would need checking on any optional fields. Actually on all fields, as presumably you would want a specific exception if a mandatory node didn't exist. This solution would just seem ugly. I'm sure there is a better way, but don't know what it is!

Comment: Use deserialization. Let the XmlSerializer figure out how to map fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search about "serialize xml to object", there are a lot of question, topic for that.

This answer for you : [C# Serialize XML to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234581/c-sharp-serialize-xml-to-object)